# How to set custom text on Progressbar in React Semantic UI

Tags: semantic-ui

Is there any way, how to set custom text on Progress component? I want to set seconds like this:

http://prntscr.com/kk7ms0

I didn't found any solution how to do this. I have percentage value, but I want set time in second with "caption" seconds.

So, I dont want to use "Label" under progressbar.

Thank you for any helpp.

Comment: I'm trying to work this out too. If I come up with a solution, I'll let you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution! It's a bit hacky, and sort of goes outside the realm of React Semantic UI but it does the job.

HTML:

```
<div className='ui progress'>
  <div className='bar' style={{width: `${percent}%`}}>
    <div className='progress progress-text'>{percent}% Completed</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.progress-text {
   text-align: center !important;
   right: 0 !important;
   left: 0 !important;
}
```

Let me know if this needs expanding on, but I think this covers your question! :)